# C header files missing to compile Sqlite3.c

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, sqlite

I tried to compile sqlite3.c from Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 developer command prompt. I'm getting errors for missing C header files. I selected all work loads in installer required for C and C++. What reference am I missing?

Input:

```
cl shell.c sqlite3.c -Fesqlite3.exe
```

Response:

> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27042 for x86
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> shell.c shell.c(85): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:
> 'stdlib.h': No such file or directory sqlite3.c C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xmmintrin.h(79):
> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'malloc.h': No such file
> or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft Docs, error C1083 is mainly caused by the following reasons.

> **The file is not included in the include search path**
>
> The compiler cannot find the file by using the search rules that are
> indicated by an #include or #import directive. For example, when a
> header file name is enclosed by quotation marks,
>
> #include "myincludefile.h"
>
> this tells the compiler to look for the file in the same directory
> that contains the source file first, and then look in other locations
> specified by the build environment. If the quotation marks contain an
> absolute path, the compiler only looks for the file at that location.
> If the quotation marks contain a relative path, the compiler looks for
> the file in the directory relative to the source directory.
>
> If the name is enclosed by angle brackets,
>
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> the compiler follows a search path that is defined by the build
> environment, the /I compiler option, the /X compiler option, and the
> INCLUDE environment variable. For more information, including specific
> details about the search order used to find a file, see #include
> Directive (C/C++) and #import Directive.
>
> If your include files are in another directory relative to your source
> directory, and you use a relative path in your include directives, you
> must use double quotes instead of angle brackets. For example, if your
> header file myheader.h is in a subdirectory of your project sources
> named headers, then this example fails to find the file and causes
> C1083:
>
> #include <headers\myheader.h>

In my opinion, the reason is: stdio.h these header files are not located in the path is not in the default path of VS2017, resulting in VS2017 can not find these header files.

I suggest that you could add the following paths in `Properties`.

> VC++ Doerctories->Include Directories: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
> Kits\10\Lib\10.0.17134.0\ucrt
>
> VC++ Doerctories->Library Directories: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
> Kits\10\Lib\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\x86

If it still doesn't work, there may be a problem with the Windows SDK. I suggest that you could reinstall Windows SDK.

Comment: As i'm working in MSVC command prompt to compile these things, can you brief how can i include these paths?

Comment: You just need to add the file path to the environment variable.

Comment: I need to add them with a new variable name or do i need to link to the existing variables?

Comment: Do not need to use new variable names.

Comment: I suggest that you could refer to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/setting-the-path-and-environment-variables-for-command-line-builds?view=msvc-160).

Comment: Configure environment variables: Windows Settings->Advanced system settings->Envirenment varibles..->System varibles->Path

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this,

- Build the project using VS developer command prompt
- Go to Visual Studio IDE project property page>C++>preprocessor.
  If *Ignore Standard include directories* is Yes, make it No. It'll work